# Store API's Json data to local Json object

Tags: javascript, json, api, python-requests

I have the following API call and a local `activesubscribers = {}` variable

```
//Add Subscriber to the List
app.post("/AddSubscriber", (req, res) => {
  const { Name, EmailAddress } = req.body;

  request(
    {
      method: "POST",
      uri: "https://website.json}",
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "Bearer" +
          "+0znPsUJtRLLInRp",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(Name, EmailAddress),
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      const data = JSON.parse(body);
    }
  );
});
```

the response from the api looks like this :

```
{
    "Results": [
        {
            "EmailAddress": "subs@example.com",
            "Name": "Person One",
        }
    ]
}
```

what i want is to get the API's response and store it to the `activesubscribers = {}` variable so i can make a validation if the user already exists in req.body user data already exist. What i have tried so far is activesubscribers = JSON.parse(data) but im stuck.

Comment: By "stuck" what do you mean? What is happening/not happening that you want to happen/not happen? Note: ` activesubscribers = JSON.parse(data)` _overwrites_ ` activesubscribers` and I'm not sure if that's what you want?